# Redefine keyboard shortcuts in JOE?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to redefine the keyboard shortcuts in [JOE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe%27s_Own_Editor) (Joe's Own Editor)? In particular, the one for `redo`?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Joe's Own Editor home page](http://joe-editor.sourceforge.net/):

> Multiple interactive keyboard macros. Macros can be assigned to key
>   sequences in joerc file.
>
> You can customize the keyboard layout, the help screens and a number
>   of behavior defaults by copying JOE's initialization file (usually
>   /home/jhallen/etc/joe/joerc) to .joerc in your home directory and then
>   by modifying it. See the section joerc below.